# Why do I get "no pg_hba.conf SSL is off" when deploying Flask app to Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, flask

I'm following a Udemy course and deploying a Flask app to Heroku.
The problem is when I type

```
heroku pg:psql --app *appname*
```

I get :

```
psql: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (0x00002746/10054)
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "37.125.61.91", user "whlcorobevpteq", database "dcmbbmbl1bbrgd", SSL off
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgres://whlcorobevpteq:a234a0b5f7300d9f6e43d566b5c849c3b1b20fb8d87ad6b994df2c18b686d624@ec2-174-129-240-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dcmbbmbl1bbrgd?sslmode=require'

db=SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_. You can [do this by running `heroku pg:credentials:rotate`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-credentials). And you shouldn't be hard-coding this value in your code. Heroku will provide it as the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. You should be doing something like `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL', default=optional_default_for_dev)`.

Comment: Note that hard-coding your config might be the cause of your problem. Heroku Postgres credentials [can change at any time](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres): "The value of your app’s `DATABASE_URL` config var might change at any time. You should not rely on this value either inside or outside your Heroku app." If your credentials have changed your hard-coded value won't be valid anymore, which might cause the error you're describing. If changing to `os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')` fixes the problem I'll add a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks but still stuck.Should my code look like this?(I'm on windows btw):    


app=Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

Comment: What does "still stuck" mean? Are you getting the same error message?

Comment: And hold on a second, what does [`heroku pg:psql`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql) have to do with the code you're showing? That command should run a `psql` shell. It has nothing to do with your code. I'm pretty sure it should use SSL out of the box. Are you sure you've got the Heroku Postgres addon provisioned? If you run `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` does it give you back a string starting with `postgres://`? (Please don't share it with us; it contains your credentials.)

Comment: Hi Chris, yes it does give me back that string. I have postgresql on heroku, the thing is I can't seem to use the psql shell. It says no pg_hba.conf entry, SSL is off. So I presumed this was related to the string where I set ?ssl=require.

Comment: Have you rotated your credentials as I suggested in my first comment? Have you ever modified your `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: Yes I have deleted and redeployed the app completely with new db url.It seems to work fine, it takes users heights and finds their averages and emails it back to the user. The only trouble is when I try to interface with the pg:psql --app *appname* command. Then it just says no pg_hba.conf for host, SSL off.

Comment: What does `psql --version` return on your local machine? How was it installed? Is it possible that it was built without SSL support?

Comment: If I type psql --version into the CMD it returns: psql (PostgreSQL) 10.7.Don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: And do you know how it was installed?

Comment: I installed it. Are you saying I may have left out a component?

Comment: Installed it _how_? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I installed it on windows. I just found the pg_hba.conf in the PostgreSQL's data directory.Do I need to edit it?

Comment: No, the error is referring to the `pg_hba.conf` on the Heroku side. I'm concerned that your local `psql` isn't trying to use SSL, which makes me wonder if it was [built without SSL support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/install-requirements.html), but if you're on Windows you probably got a pre-built version that almost certainly includes SSL. Can you connect if you manually run `psql` with the user, password, host, and database provided by Heroku and `sslmode=require`?

Comment: So when i run psql:postgres://*********************?sslmode=require in the cli it returns psql: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (0x00002746/10054)

Comment: That looks like an internal OpenSSL error message. Troubleshooting that is going to be tricky. Can you try upgrading to PostgreSQL 11?

Comment: Yes ,I'll give it a shot. BTW when I go into my app settings on Heroku, it says SSL:Upgrade to paid dynos to configure Heroku SSL.Even though I'm on Hobby-dev plan.(edit downloading PostgreSQL 11 and redeploying had no effect)

Comment: Heroku SSL has nothing to do with Postgres SSL.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll keep looking then.